# Angular: error, not installed as it should

Tags: linux, angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

I'm new to Angular 2 and Angular CLI environment.

I'm working on a project and when tried installing angular CLI and related stuff. It got installed but:

When ng --version is checked

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.1
Node: 6.12.2
OS: linux x64
Angular: error
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router


typescript: error
webpack: error
```

I've repeated the installation again, but still the same happens at the end of it.

I can't get where I made a mistake.

Kindly guide me through this.

P.S: I am trying to run an existing project, not a creating a new one.

**Update:**
On following the lead given by *@maddy23285* in comments, it worked but a new issue stating PostCSS plugin emerged.

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.2
Node: 6.12.2
OS: linux x64
Angular: 5.1.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.36
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.22
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.42
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.2
@schematics/angular: 0.1.11
@schematics/schematics: 0.0.11
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.10.0
telekha-01@telekha01-H81M-S:~/workspace/rajtelekha-survey-track-web-
de11d86a7c75$ ng serve
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open 
your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
14% building modules 40/48 modules 8 
active...odules/@angular/router/esm5/router.jsUnknown error from 
PostCSS plugin. Your current PostCSS version is 6.0.15, but 
autoprefixer uses 5.2.18. Perhaps this is the source of the error 
below.
91% additional chunk assets processingError: ENOENT: no such file or 
directory, open '/home/telekha-01/workspace/rajtelekha-survey-track-
web-de11d86a7c75/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
at Error (native)
```

Comment: You may want to run `docker run -it ubuntu:xenial` and try to reproduce the problem there, just to figure out whether you do something wrong or it's something wrong with your installation/permissions.

Comment: If you are running existing project that was working fine before, open node command shell and go to project directory where package.json is residing and run this command: npm install

Comment: @maddy23285 that did work. Thanks. I was running it in an incorrect path. I changed the path and it worked. But a new issue regarding PostCSS plugin emerged.

Comment: does your package.json has dependency entry for PostCss plugin? if not please issue this command in directory where you issued npm install command : npm install --save-dev gulp-postcss also check availability of all prerequisites for postcss.

Comment: @maddy23285 tried the command. It installed few components,but still same error emerges. :(

Comment: First run this command : **npm install --save-dev gulp-postcss@'5.2.18'** and also check **jquery.min.js** is located in **/home/telekha-01/workspace/rajtelekha-survey-track-
web-de11d86a7c75/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js**

Comment: There is no valid version of _PostCSS_  as  _5.2.18_ and nothing related to 
 _jquery_  in  node_modules.